# How to Load the Data with out text qualifiers using PIG/HIVE/Hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-pig

I Have One CSV file, Which Contains text qualifier(" ") data. I want to load the data into hdfs using PIG/Hive/Hbase without text qualifiers. plz give your help

```
my file input.CSV
"Id","Name"
"1","Raju"
"2","Anitha"
"3","Rakesh"
```

I want output like:

```
Id,Name
1,Raju
2,Anitha
3,Rakesh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in pig script

Suppose your input file name is **input.csv**

1.First move this input file to HDFS using copyfromlocal command.
2. Run this below pig script

**PigScript:**
**HDFS mode:**

```
A = LOAD 'hdfs://<hostname>:<port>/user/test/input.csv' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'"(.*)","(.*)"')) AS (id:int,name:chararray);
STORE B INTO '/user/test/output' USING PigStorage(',');
```

**Local mode:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.csv' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'"(.*)","(.*)"')) AS (id:int,name:chararray);
STORE B INTO 'output' USING PigStorage(',');
```

**Output:**

```
Id,Name
1,Raju
2,Anitha
3,Rakesh
```

Comment: Thanks for your Comment Jayaraman!!! I will try using this script. Thank You Once again!!

Comment: I Tried with above code... Then it gets error message like: Input(s): Failed to read data from "hdfs:/input.csv"      Output(s): Failed to produce result in "hdfs:/PIGRESULTS"

Comment: Its looks like some config issue. Can you try to run the pig script in local mode instead of hdfs. create a input file "input.csv" and pig script file say "test.pig". Copy the above code and change the first line alone to A = LOAD 'input.csv' AS line;  and execute the pig script in command line   "pig -x local test.pig".

Comment: Updated the local mode solution also in the answer section. Run the pig script "pig -x local test.pig" and go to 'output' folder and check the result in the file name starts with 'part*'

Comment: Now I have 2 columns So, you used regular expression like '"(.*)","(.*)"'. Suppose I have 3 columns then Shall i increase one more like '"(.*)","(.*)","(.*)"' or The above formula work properly.

Plz clarify my doubt.